# How to change the used java version of SoapUI?

Tags: java, linux, soapui

I have multiple Java versions installed. I switch versions when needed.
If I use Java 8 as default, SoapUI will use it. A Popup with with this error will show then :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/eviware/soapui/SoapUI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Since the 5.6.0, SoapUI need a Java version ⩾ 9. So I want to specify the java version used by SoapUI when my default version is java 8.

**Notes :**
By default I mean, the version printed when : `java -version` is executed on the Terminal.

Answer (score 11):

In the file `SoapUI-5.6.0/bin/SoapUI-5.6.0` :

1. Uncomment the var `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE` at the beginning of the file
2. Assign the java home (JRE OU JDK) to `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE`

Example :
`INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-11/`

Answer (score 1):

I leave here my solution since i lost 4 hours just to understand that if you have java 8 and you use Ubuntu, you can save the world but SoapUI 5.6.0 won't work.

So the solution is to download an older version, like 5.4.0

Don't bother looking for one if you're an Ubuntu lady/guy, just use this command:

```
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.eviware/soapuios/5.4.0/SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz
```

Then unzip and untar the downloaded archive:

```
$ gunzip SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz
$ tar xvf SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar
```

Finally start SoapUI by entering in the folder where it is installed and run:

```
/bin/soapui.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

in case it helps anyone - I have **java-11** alongside **java-8** (with latter being the default) and SoapUI-5.6.0.

**Solution:** I've set the INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE variable in SoapUI-5.6.0 to:

> INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"

Just use nano or gedit, etc. to modify (don't forget to use elevated permissions, if neccessary).

Best regards